# Functions return types not resolved correctly when called in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've created a simple map with two functions that take a single 'foo: string' argument and implement a various functions that are directly returned:

```
import { mapValues } from 'lodash';

const fun1 = (foo: string) => (name: string, surname: string) => {};
const fun2 = (foo: string) => (age: number) => {};

interface Actions {
  fun1: typeof fun1;
  fun2: typeof fun2;
}

const actions: Actions = { fun1, fun2 };

const mappedActions = mapValues(actions, action => action('bar'));

mappedActions.fun1(1);
```

With `mapValues`, I'm looping through those functions and invoke them with some common parameter. What I'd expect is a map of the *semi-called* functions assigned in `mappedActions` map, but there is still a problem with the types.

`fun1` is not resolved as a function that takes `(name: string, surname: string)` arguments, but still the top level one.

How should I compose that to make TypeScript resolve the types correctly?

[image]

Comment: Does `mapValues` use a mapped type?

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, `action('bar')` is resolved correctly, so requires one string parameter. Passing anything else gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to resolve types properly:

```js
import { mapValues } from 'lodash';

const fun1 = (foo: string) => (name: string, surname: string) => {};
const fun2 = (foo: string) => (age: number) => {};

type FunctionDictionary = { [id: string]: ((...args: any[]) => any) };

interface Actions extends FunctionDictionary {
  fun1: typeof fun1;
  fun2: typeof fun2;
}

const actions: Actions = { fun1, fun2 };

type ReturnTypeDict<T> = T extends { [id: string]: ((...args: any[]) => any) } ? {
  [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>;
} : never;

const map: (actions: Actions) =>  ReturnTypeDict<Actions> = actions => {
  return mapValues(actions, action => action('bar')) as ReturnTypeDict<Actions>;
}

const mappedActions = map(actions);

mappedActions.fun1(1);
```

The key here is the ReturnType conditional type. In order to use it you have to create your own conditional type:

```js
type ReturnTypeDict<T> = T extends { [id: string]: ((...args: any[]) => any) } ? {
  [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>;
} : never;
```

And now you have to explicitly say that your interface extends needed dictionary type:

```js
type FunctionDictionary = { [id: string]: ((...args: any[]) => any) };

interface Actions extends FunctionDictionary {
  fun1: typeof fun1;
  fun2: typeof fun2;
}
```

Then you create a function that properly maps data:

```js
const map: (actions: Actions) =>  ReturnTypeDict<Actions> = actions => {
  return mapValues(actions, action => action('bar')) as ReturnTypeDict<Actions>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I copied your snippet to CodeSandbox and analyzed Lodash's function `mapValues()` and I think types for `mapValues()` not match your purpose.

```
mapValues<T extends object, TResult>(obj: T | null | undefined, callback: ObjectIterator<T, TResult>): { [P in keyof T]: TResult };
```

As you can see, function mapValues takes an object (`T extends object`) and for each key of this object, assign `TResult` which makes this:

```
mapValues<Actions, ((name: string, surname: string) => void) | ((age: number) => void)>(obj: Actions, callback: ObjectIterator<Actions, ((name: string, surname: string) => void) | ((age: number) => void)>): {
```

I tried to use lodash (especially *lodash/fp*) with TypeScript and I can say not everything works perfectly, also it's very hard to create *universal* typings for all possibilities.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So is that even possible to achieve in TS with a regular loop over `Object.values`?